# how to catch some elements on html without any properties?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make a display: none; at "founds 2 result" et "page 1 to 1" but I don't know how to catch them.
Thanks a lot !

[image]

Comment: Hi Celine, do you have some code as an example of what you're trying to achieve please?

Comment: Please provide snippets showing what you've tried so far, and try to elaborate on the end result you're trying to achieve. Sounds like you should Google around for good tutorials on how to do Pagination.

Comment: put them inside `<span>` tags

Comment: I do not have any html file (I'm working with plugin on wordpress)

Comment: have a look at the answers bellow

Answer (score 0):

try with css

```
.search-filter-results#search-filter-results-540{
  display:none;
}
```

or Js

```
var element=document.getElementById('search-filter-results-5');
  element.style.cssText="display:none;";
```

Comment: but still valid ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Can I select a text element that is outside HTML tags?

You can't because the text you want to modify **is not an element**.

You should always write content inside tags, let them be `<span>` or `<p>` tags. This way you can easily select them, style them etc...

In your case you can still work around this by selecting the closest parent element hoping that it doesn't hold other elements you don't want to affect:

```
.search-filter-results {

  display: none;

}
```

Again I'm not sure that `search-filter-results` only contains the elements you want to hide. Maybe it contains other elements, in this case it will hide it too.

Comment: If I do so, I'm losing all the results and I would like just remove the text

Comment: @RenzoCC ah, fair enough

Comment: So I can't select them if there are not tag... Thanks for you quick reply

Comment: Basically you can only select tags